# How to use css transform-origin to show a circle of playing cards (rectangles)?

Tags: html, css, transform, css-transforms

Someone has requested this for their website. Basically there are 12 cards and when you hover over a card another div is displayed with some content inside it. The 12 cards need to be arranged in a circle. I've managed to do part of this using CSS rotation - but I can't seem to space the cards out. Margin's don't seem to work, I assume that is down to the `transform-origin`?

I've shown this is the following Codepen: http://codepen.io/moy/pen/oIsLH

Ideally there should be spaces inbetween and below each card/rectangle. Kinda of like a game of 'clock'.

The only way I can come up with is to make the list-items bigger and then put another div inside which would be the 'card'. This would be narrower than the width of the list-item which would create the margins?

[image]

Comment: Add pictures to both q and a and added tags and made title more useful for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the transform origin *outside* of the 'card':

```
transform-origin: center 600px;
```

http://codepen.io/moob/pen/rAzdh

[image]

Comment: Doh! Never crossed my mind to use a pixel value, silly me. Thanks a lot for clearing this up! :)